# Web Speech API running in the background

Tags: javascript, background, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

Can Web Speech API (both speech synthesis and speech recognition) be running in the background? E.g. when we use our phone to dictate what we say using Web Speech API while open another app (so the browser is closed).

Comment: Short Answer, No. Your App is allowed to access up to 1 Minute on Android and 0 seconds on iOS to the Microphone after the App is leaving foreground. The System only wont suspent the Application if it produce an audible constant audio output, while being in background